# How do I create a loop that continues until the original value is repeated?

Tags: python

I'm reading a series of values, like 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5

The first value will always be 4 and others will always be >4 until another 4 is reached. I want to continue the loop, but stop before the next 4 is reached.

So my desired output would be: 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6

```
for value in list:
    print(value)
```

I'm  sure it's simple, but I can't think of the logic to stop the loop

```
for value in list:
    print(value)
    
    if value == 4:
       break
```

If I do this, it stops at the first 4 of course.  How do I get the logic to ignore the first 4 and only apply that if value == 4, after the first loop cycle?

Comment: set a flag for the first "4" and exit only if "4" and the flag is set

Comment: but he doesn't want to ignore the first item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplest logic I could figure out. Use a flag, set it if you meet the value, but first check if already set.

```
lst = [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5]

four_met = False
for e in lst:
    if e == 4:
        if four_met:
            break
        four_met = True
    print(e)
```

Comment: do we need loop  lst[ : lst[ 1 : ].index(4) +1]

Comment: @DeepakTripathi yes, finding the first occurrence of 4 with `index` is a good idea. Slicing the list isn't, because it creates a sublist. But using `itertools.islice` would fix that

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter:

```py
num_4s = 0
for value in list:
    if value == 4:
       num_4s += 1
    
    if num_4s > 1:
       break

    print(value)
```

This would probably even help someone who has to count more than one original value before stopping.

Comment: This won't produce his desired output

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are multiple options, which one is 'correct' would depend on your exact use case. You could skip the first element within your loop:

```
print(data[0])
for value in data[1:]:    
    if value == 4:
       break

    print(value)
```

You could also add an additional check for the index:

```
for i, value in enumerate(data):
    if value == 4 and i > 0:
       break

    print(value)
```

Comment: dang, you beat me by 22 seconds :P

Comment: This is. wonky answer.  The `print` probably represents a more complex block of code.  You'd have to have two copies of all of that code.

Comment: True, but then you could still avoid the duplicate code by introducing another function. Perhaps that is not the most elegant though...

Comment: This won't produce his desired output

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the index of the list.

```
some_list = [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5]
for value in range(len(some_list)):
    print(some_list[value])

    if some_list[value + 1] == 4:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution

```
l = [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5]

f = None
idx = 0

while l[idx] not in (f,):
    f = l[0]
    print (l[idx])
    idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag.

```
found_4 = False
for value in list:
    print(value)
    
    if value == 4:
       if not found_4:
           found_4 = True
       else:
           break
```

If you need to stop at, say, the third occurrence of a 4, then you can make the flag an integer instead and count up to it.

Comment: you can make a simpler condition without negatives `if found_4: break` then `found_4 = True`

Comment: True, but that makes the logic marginally less clear for the sake of demonstration.

Comment: This won't produce his desired output

Answer (score 0):

If your stopping condition don't depend on the first element of the list, you can just skip it.

```
print(list[0])
for value in list[1:]:    
    if value == 4:
       break
    print(value)
```

If for example, you wanted to design this in a way where your stopping condition depends on the first item, you can do:

```
stop_value = list[0]
print(stop_value)
for value in list[1:]:    
    if value == stop_value:
       break
    print(value)
```

Comment: But he clearly wants to process the first element, per his desired output

Comment: @Steve Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: These won't produce his desired output

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you may help you.

```
n = [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5]
new = [4]
for i in range(1, len(n)):
    
    if n[i] != 4:
        new.append(n[i])
    else:
        break
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done without for loop like this :

```
l =  [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5]
print(l[:l[1:].index(4) +1])
```

Comment: `l[:l[1:].index(4)+1]`

Comment: yead missed that one but this is just a simple approach

Comment: would be better with: `l[:l[1:].index(l[0])+1]`